# Convert from string datetime in ISO format to ANSI

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a varchar column that provides datetimes in the following format

yyyymmddhhmmss

In order to store this in a datetime2 column I need to convert it to ANSI format

yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

There is a convert function I have used for similar columns formatted in UK format e.g. 04/10/2023 11:15:00 can be solved with CONVERT(datetime2(0),COLUMN,103).

The issue is I face an error when attempting this with

```
SELECT TOP (5) 
       [HistoryID]
      ,[CheckedBy]
      ,[CheckedTime]
      ,CheckedTime2 = SUBSTRING(CheckedTime,1,4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(CheckedTime,5,2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(CheckedTime,7,2) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(CheckedTime,9,2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(CheckedTime,11,2) + ':'  + SUBSTRING(CheckedTime,13,2)
      --,CONVERT(datetime2(0),CheckedTime,112)  
      ,CONVERT(datetime2(0),
      SUBSTRING(CheckedTime,1,4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(CheckedTime,5,2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(CheckedTime,7,2) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(CheckedTime,9,2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(CheckedTime,11,2) + ':'  + SUBSTRING(CheckedTime,13,2)
      ,120) AS [CheckedTime3]
      ,[RevokedBy]
      ,[RevokedTime]
      ,[AnalystRef]
  FROM [staging].[AccuracyChecks]
```

The above generates the following

| HistoryID | CheckedBy | CheckedTime | CheckedTime2 | CheckedTime3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 63061C5F-0062-02056B95 | 1 | 20220825082057 | 2022-08-25 08:20:57 | 2022-08-25 08:20:57 |
| 63061C5F-0062-02056B96 | 1 | 20220825082057 | 2022-08-25 08:20:57 | 2022-08-25 08:20:57 |
| 63061CBC-0062-02056B97 | 1 | 20220825082053 | 2022-08-25 08:20:53 | 2022-08-25 08:20:53 |
| 63061CBC-0062-02056B98 | 1 | 20220825082053 | 2022-08-25 08:20:53 | 2022-08-25 08:20:53 |
| 63061E55-0062-02056B99 | 1 | 20220825082026 | 2022-08-25 08:20:26 | 2022-08-25 08:20:26 |

As you can see when I use the substring method or convert with the substring method, it generates it correctly.

The commented-out line

```
CONVERT(datetime2(0),CheckedTime,112)
```

produces the following error

**Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.**

The only difference I can see in the docs is the style code 112 does not include TIME data.

What would be the correct way to convert to the required format as using the SUBSTRING method causes a different error related to a filter which I have previously had help resolving through the CONVERT function.

Although I doubt it matters, I have no control over the format I receive the data in.

Comment: I am unsure why the table isn't formatted as it showed correctly in the preview

Comment: Adding an extra line break before the markdown table sorts that out

Comment: Nither `yyyymmddhhmmss` nor `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` is ISO 8601 compliant.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - there are a lot of acceptable formats for ISO 8601

Comment: Try specifying a "T" between the date and time instead of space: `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`

Comment: @ZoharPeled Correct, It should say ANSI, I have updated the body and title.

Comment: @MartinSmith Please correct me if I'm wrong, but AFAIK, Date & time ISO8601 is either `yyyymmddThhmmss` or `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss` (with or without time zone information).

Comment: The wikipedia article indicates a lot more options https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times - and also that the `T` depends on version of  ISO 8601

Comment: Yes, for date only / time only / duration and such. but not for the combination of date and time

Comment: @MartinSmith "In ISO 8601:2004 it was permitted to omit the "T" character by mutual agreement as in "200704051430",[36] but this provision was removed in ISO 8601-1:2019. Separating date and time parts with other characters such as space is not allowed in ISO 8601, but allowed in its profile RFC 3339."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations

Comment: `using the SUBSTRING method causes a different error` -> but you said it works fine. Why not try to solve that _different_ error instead?

Comment: @AaronBertrand The issue is being caused in a MERGE that has a check on a column not shown above. The SUBSTRING works on SELECT but the MERGE error (conversion happening before the where check) was mitigated using CONVERT for a different date style.

Comment: Well, [I'm not a big fan of `MERGE` anyway](https://sqlblog.org/merge), but maybe you can get past it using `TRY_CONVERT()` instead of `CONVERT()`. But it's hard to imagine how we might help you solve _that_ problem from a vague description - IMHO _that_ should be the problem your question focuses on. Because no matter how you coerce a date stored as a string into a date, if the engine is trying to access that column before the convert has happened, or the filter happens too late to filter out the garbage that creeps into such columns, you're still going to be stuck.

Comment: (You should always remember that in `SELECT expression FROM ... WHERE filter` that the `expression` might happen before the `filter`. One workaround is to use `CASE` around expression but again it's hard to suggest how without more details about the error scenario.)

Comment: And honestly, the thing I would work on fixing **first** is fixing the data type of that column. There is no good reason a date/time value should be stored as a string, never mind a non-standard one that requires `CONVERT()` just to be understood as a date/time. Even if you can't change the incoming format from some other source, you can manipulate it _before_ you store it in the table (this is why we often use staging tables).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks Aaron, it is a staging table that the data is being held in varchar format. I did attempt the TRY_CONVERT before reaching out but the issue was all values returned as NULL. As I mentioned in the question, I think it is the fact that there is a time component. If it was just a date then CONVERT(datetime2(0),CheckedDate,112)  it works, it is only when TIME is included that it fails, the MS Docs show Style 112 with a date only in the example but no style is date and time in that format

Comment: I would strongly suggest adding to your staging table a Datetime2 column that will contain the properly converted value of your varchar column using a combination of `substring` and `try_convert`  like in this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_CfQkesW) example

Comment: if substring method fails in some cases, it means there are dates that has another format altogether? you could do `select * from yourtable where try_convert(datetime, substring(...)) is null and substring(...) is not null; `

Comment: Thanks @siggemannen, the SELECT was fine it was the MERGE that was an issue, and it was down to an order of operation issue.

Comment: Thank you @ZoharPeled, clever little work-a-round, but the important thing is it worked. If you can add an answer, I would be happy to mark it as accepted.

Comment: If possible, what you really should do is convert that value to proper DateTime2 *before* storing it into the staging table as @AaronBertrand wrote in his comment. You should only add another column in case you don't have control over the input process. Anyways, now that you know how to solve the problem, you can go ahead and post an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in answer to my original question, it doesn't appear that there is a way to use CONVERT with it in that format style (yyyymmddhhmmss).

Upon suggestion in the comments, I added a new datetime2 column to the staging table. Using this new column, I altered the SP to update that column using the original SUBSTRING method, only for the filtered records I was working on at that time. I was able to then use the newly created column in the MERGE statement and this avoided the order of operation error seen before.